# Set DataSource URL to filepath?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

In [this video](https://youtu.be/0oVM79TS6R8?t=1548) the database gets stores as `target/db.h2.db` as he configures

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:target/db");
```

as the URL of his `DataSource`. I am using PostgreSQL and it seems that this does not work the same way. I am using:

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql:target/db");
```

but I'm getting

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "file:target/db" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:684)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:199)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
```

How can I write my database schema into `target` as file?

Comment: Please check the manual for the correct URL syntax: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I've just checked but I can't find a way to set something like a filepath here. Is it even possible to do what I need here?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "database file" in Postgres. You connect to a running database _server_. You don't "open files"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hm, okay. That means each time I want to run the script from scratch I'd have to drop all my tables first, right?

Comment: Why would you want to drop the tables? Normally tables are created to persist data over time, not be dropped every time the application starts. I'm pretty sure the users of your application will be quite disappointed when the data is lost when restarting the application.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, not on each startup of my application but during development. While I am writing SQL I'm running the same script multiple times. I can't commit any `DROP TABLE` statements in those files and therefore I'd have to let FlywayDB rebuild my schema each time I run it. It might not be optimal and I am very open to suggestions but it's my first time trying to write a larger database. ^^

Comment: I do not drop tables during development. A tool like Flyway (I only use Liquibase but the concept is the same) is made to do *incremental* migrations. Why would you want to re-create your DB from scratch every time? What about your test data?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hmm, well maybe I'm doing it wrong but e.g. if I'm writing a larger script that creates tables, adds foreign key etc. etc. how do you check if your script actually works? You'd have to execute it in order to check what it's doing, or not? Or how would you e.g. test some smaller changes?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Basically the question is "How does my database look like while I'm writing on a script that makes changes to it and does it even work". ^^ But I guess I wouldn't be surprised if you'd tell me now that I misunderstood a very basic concept here because I'm having that feeling for quite a while now. ^^